# creating random number in range and accessing arrayindex char

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, random, terminal

I'm trying to get a random character print out in an array that is stored with characters. I'm new to bash and been looking at some guides along the way but have run into a bit of a problem.

I create an array to test with which stores chars. I then have a variable called Range which is 21 (this is the length of the array).

```
 #create an characters to test with
 letters=(a,b,e,g,i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,x,w,z)

 RANGE=21
```

I then try and get a random number from 0 -> range, so it will correspond with array indices. I then need to access the array index of the random number and store that in a variable called `arraychar`. I have done it like this:

```
number=$RANDOM%$RANGE #gets int of a random number between 0 and range (size of array)
arraychar=${letters[$number]} #chooses a random char from array and stores in arraychar
```

Then I want to pass this letter as an argument to my executable like so:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`;do
   echo $i " "
   ./sample-tree -$arraychar
done
```

It keeps hanging here, and I'm not too sure what's it doing, and why it isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm a newbie!

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the syntax for creating an array in bash. You should have spaces, not commas, between the elements.

Comment: `letters=({a..z})` syntax also works (at least on bash 4..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with the code snippets in your post.

`letters=(a,b,e,g,i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,x,w,z)` is an array of one element. See what `declare -p letters` spits out at you to confirm. sh arrays are whitespace separated lists.

The length of an array in the shell is available via `${#letters[@]}`.

`number=$RANDOM%$RANGE` is not doing what you expect it is. Again see what `declare -p number` says the value of the variable is (`echo "$number"` would work too).

You need [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to evaluate the modulus operation (i.e. `number=$((RANDOM % RANGE))`).

A couple other "stylistic" points as well:

- You don't need `$` in the array indexing context (e.g. `${letters[$number]}` can be written as `${letters[number]}`).
- In bash (and many other shells) you can use `{1..3}` to get that list of numbers without needing a sub-shell and seq.
- The trailing space in `echo $i " "` isn't going to do much for you because `echo` outputs a newline as well (unless you use `-n` but in that case you might just be better off with `printf`).

Comment: `declare -a letters='([0]="a,b,e,g,i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,x,w,z")'`

Thanks, I'll try this again.

Comment: @user3530774 Right, notice the `[0]` there? That's the index. See how there is only one? Compare that to `l=(a b c d); declare -p l`.

Comment: @EtanReisner +1. Probably not hugely important here, but worth nothing that you shouldn't use `$RANDOM` for anything important, especially since depending on RANGE it may not even be expected to produce an even distribution of random numbers (since `$RANDOM` will be a pseudo random number between 0...32767)

Comment: Per @BroSlow on distribution, and bearing @EtanReiser's comments in mind. Assuming you get `letters` declared as an array, you need something like: `CHOICE=$(echo "scale=6; $RANDOM/32767 * ${#letters}" | bc); CHOICE=${CHOICE/.*}; CHOICE=${CHOICE:-0}`. Obviously this begs to be defined as a function with $1 replacing ${#letters}.